# Can't create new virtual devices from Netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans, permissions, android-virtual-device

I use Netbeans on an Java/Android Development VM with Ubuntu 13.10 and I am having a problem. Whenever I would try to start AVD Manager from `Netbeans --> Tools --> AVD Manager`, I got an Permission Denied error. So I searched Google and poked around my file system a little and I found out that my AVDs are stored in `/root/avd/`.

Then I tried starting Netbeans as root and then creating a AVD and voila - no more permission denied error. My android sdk is installed in my `/home/` directory.

So does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try starting the Virtual device by starting directly the AVD manager, not through net beans?

Comment: Yes, when I start it with sudo, it works. Without, I get the same permission denied error.